# communication(interfacing) between unitronics V1040 plc and raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian

hi im doing a project based on unitronics V1040 plc. but i need to get the output HMI screen as per the plc to raspberry pi by using webpage. can anyone can help any method to interface plc and raspberry. i found modbus will help to interface but some clear idea..

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://unitronicsplc.com/vision-series-vision1040/#1449515771593-63d974b6-05ac1451602511853) on the vendors website states the unit has serial ports, a USB 'programming' port and a number of others.

The downloadable installation manual states:

> The Unitronics Setup CD contains VisiLogic software and other
>   utilities
>
> - VisiLogic
>
>   Easily configure hardware and write both HMI and
>     Ladder control applications; the Function Block library simplifies
>     complex tasks such as PID. Write your application, and then download
>     it to the controller via the programming cable included in the kit.
> - Utilities
>
>   These include UniOPC server, Remote Access for remote
>     programming and diagnostics, and DataXport for run-time data logging.

I would expect the **DataXport** application would help you...

Answer (score -1):

You can use new PLC platform Speedplc for Raspberry Pi.

https://www.fultek.com.tr/en/speed-plc/

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.